# Unlink multiple images from root folder

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, unlink

I am trying to delete and unlink multiple images with this logic :

1. Click delete from view and `id` of images to delete will passed to controller
2. From controller get the `id` using `get method` and send to model to check related images from database.
3. From model, if exist, hold images list into array and send back to model to proceed to unlink.
4. Back to controller, foreach images to unlink.
5. If unlink success, proceed to delete images from database.

my controller

```
$imageToDelete = $this->Wallpaper_model->loadImage();

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads/";

foreach ($imageToDelete as $deletRow) {

    unlink($path.$deletRow);

}
```

my model

```
public function loadImage(){
    $this->db->select('image');
    $this->db->from('tblimg');
    $this->db->where('groupid', $this->getId());

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    if($data != null){
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using those coding I am getting error at `unlink` in the controller where the `$deleteRow` resulting `Array` as quotes below.

> Message: unlink(root-folder-goes-here/Array): No such file or
>   directory

What is the proper way to unlink images from the folder? Thank you.

**EDIT**

`print_array($imageToDelete)` result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => 5948db352524e.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image] => 5948db352524e1.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image] => 5948db352524e2.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: So start by doing a `print_r($imageToDelete);` to find out what you are processing as it is obviously not what you hoped it would be. Then add the result to your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did print the `$imageToDelete` and it displaying all list of images. But when I put in the foreach the error showing the name as `Array`

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($imageToDelete);`

Comment: your code is correct use my answer.

Comment: @VK321 let me try it first.

Comment: Use `$deletRow['image']` to unlink!

Comment: Sure .. try it and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$deletRow` is array. Your query is returning more than one row on groupid

Use

```
// column name from db
$deletRow['image']
```